# How to define default input value when merging two datasets on one column of different lengths?

Tags: r, merge

Assuming I have an original version dataset containing a complete set of "texsts" (a string variable), and a second dataset that only contains those "texts" for which the new variable "value" takes a certain value (0, 1, or NA).

Now I would like to merge them back together so that the resulting dataset contains the full range of "texts" from the first dataset but also includes "value" which should be 0 if coded 0 *and/or* only present in the original dataset.

```
dat1<-data.frame(text=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"))     # original dataset
dat2<-data.frame(text=c("e","f","g","h"), value=c(0,NA,1,1))  # second version
```

The final dataset should look like this:

```
> dat3
  text value
1    a     0
2    b     0
3    c     0
4    d     0
5    e     0
6    f    NA
7    g     1
8    h     1
```

However, what Base-R's `merge()` does is to introduce `NA`s where I want `0`s instead:

```
dat3<-merge(dat1, dat2, by=c("text"), all=T)
```

Is there a way to define a default input for when the variable by which datasets are merged is only present in one but not the other dataset? In other words, how can I define `0` as standard input value instead of `NA`?

I am aware of the fact that I could temporarily change the coded `NA`s in the second dataset to something else to distinguish later on between "real" `NA`s and `NA`s that just get introduced, but I would really like to refrain from doing so, if there's another, cleaner way. Ideally, I would like to use `merge()` or `plyr::join()` for that purpose but couldn't find anything in the manual(s).

Comment: I was also thinking about writing a for loop, but I have no idea what that might look like. `for (i in dat2$text) {ifelse(i == dat1$text), __merge__, __paste(0)__}` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is not ideal too, but something to consider:

```
library(dplyr)
dat3 <- dplyr::left_join(dat1,dat2,all.x =T)
dat3[which(dat2$text != dat3$text),2] = 0
```

Or wrapping in a function to call a one-liner:

```
merge_NA <- function(dat1,dat2){
  dat3 <- dplyr::left_join(dat1,dat2,all.x = T)
  dat3[which(dat2$text != dat3$text),2] = 0
  return(dat3)
}
```

Now, you only call:

```
merge_NA(dat1,dat2)
```

Comment: OK, that technically works, but I'm still wondering if there might not be a way to do it all in one step in the process of merging the datasets.

Comment: you can wrap this in a function and always call it. I've edited the response. Hope, this helps.

Comment: Right, that's a nice solution! It's still a two step process though, and on top of that it's very specific to this case and dataset names and variable names. - What I was trying instead is to find the `merge()` source code and adjust it so that you can set the default input value. Wasn't able to find the source code, though. It only tells me that `merge()` calls `UseMethode("merge")` ... which isn't particularly helpful.